# Copy hex values with sprintf in C

Tags: c, printf

From the code below I am trying to get the result of the result var into a string var but no success so far.
What's wrong? Why I can't get the right result? If I print this directly it's ok...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/md5.h>

char *string = "stelios";
unsigned char s[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
int main()
{
 int i;
 unsigned char result[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];

  MD5(string, strlen(string), result);

  // output
  for(i = 0; i < MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++){
   sprintf(s,"%0x", result[i]);//
   printf("%x",s[i]);
  }
   printf("\n%x",s);

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  }
```

Comment: What is the error you're seeing? It looks like your string buffer is just not big enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/md5.h>

char *string = "stelios";
char s[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2 + 1] = "";
int main()
{
  int i;
  unsigned char result[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];

  MD5(string, strlen(string), result);

  // output
  for(i = 0; i < MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++){
    char temp[3];
    sprintf(temp, "%02x", result[i]);
    strcat(s, temp);
  }
  printf("Final Hex String: %s",s);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Each time `sprintf` is called, it writes the formatted value to the *beginning* of `s`, overwriting whatever was written there in the previous call.  You need to do something like `sprintf(s + i*2, "%02x", result[i]);` (and change the length of `s` to `2*MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH+1`).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've used:

```
  char *digit="0123456789abcdef";
  char hex[2*MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH+1],*h;
  int i;
  for (h=hex,i=0; i<N; i++)
  {
   *h++=digit[digest[i] >> 4];
   *h++=digit[digest[i] & 0x0F];
  }
  *h='\0';
```